# Arrays: Location of certain Values Inputed

Tags: java

So I would like to output the location of a certain value in an array. how do I output the location of a value of an array? (example after the code):

```
public class Journal5b {

public int[] [] createArray (int rSize , int cSize)
{
    int [] [] array = new int [rSize][cSize];
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int[] array1 : array) {
        for (int column = 0; column < array[0].length; column++) {
            array1[column] = r.nextInt(26);
        }
    }

    return array;
}

public void print2DArray (int [] [] array)
{
    for (int[] array1 : array) {
        for (int column = 0; column < array[0].length; column++) {
            System.out.print(array1[column] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}

public int countInstance (int [] [] array, int searchForNum)
{
    int count = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) 
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < array[0].length; column++) {
            if (array[row][column] == searchForNum) {

                count++;
            }
        }
    }
     return count; 
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
 Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    int [] [] myArray;
    Journal5b j5b = new Journal5b();
    myArray = j5b.createArray(10, 10);
    j5b.print2DArray(myArray);

   int val;
   System.out.println("Enter the number to search for ");
    val = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Your Number popped up " + j5b.countInstance(myArray, val) + " times"); 
} 
}
```

So the output I would look something like this:

```
22  20  12  25  10  8   3   4   12  25  

11  24  0   7   3   21  23  9   23  11  

22  18  10  24  11  13  0   25  8   18  

 7  14  0   5   11  12  9   22  0   16  

14  11  12  4   16  3   20  22  18  25  

 8  24  12  6   25  4   3   16  10  23  

 23 11  8   12  19  15  3   25  12  6   

 10 3   5   22  11  7   0   7   4   4   

 18 1   14  23  7   13  9   9   12  9   

 20 10  6   14  13  1   9   15  0   3   

 Enter the number to search for 
 10
 Your number popped up 5 times and is located on row 0,2,5,7, 9
```

How do I output what i want to output if that makes sense... I'm trying to add on to countInstance and find the location of that certain number thats being inputed by each row.

I have this code done for the most part however I've hit a wall with this part of the code. I can't find out my next step.I want to add `is located on row 0,2,5,7, 9`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should add more details to help us understand where you're stuck. "I've hit a wall" does not give us much information: Are you getting a compilation error? Is your code giving the wrong output? If so, include your output in addition to the expected output.

Comment: @jadhachem I don't know what to do next.....I want to add `is located on row 0,2,5,7, 9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I understand now,
Sorry I had to completely refactor your code a bit.

```
public class Journal5b {

   private int[] rowSpotted;//variable to keep rows of searched number
   private int[][] arrayToBeSearched; 

   public class Journal5b (int rows, int columns) {

       rowSpotted = new int[rows];
       arrayToBeSearched = new int[rows][columns];
       this.createArray();
       this.print2dArray();
   }

   private void createArray() {
      Random r = new Random();
      for (int[] array1 : arrayToBeSearched) {
         for (int number: array1) {
               number = r.nextInt(26);
         }
      }
   }

   //I removed the array local variable array so that you won't have to keep passing it as an argument, It's now an instance variable.
   //You can also use a for each loop to populate the inner array, no need to use the for loop.

  public void print2DArray () {
     for (int[] array1 : arrayToBeSearched) {
         for (int num: array1) {
           System.out.print(num + "\t");
         }
      System.out.println("\n");
     }
  }

  //just prints the array to be searched.

  public int countInstance (int searchForNum) {
      int count = 0;

      for (int row = 0; row < arrayToBeSearched.length; row++) {
          for (int column = 0; column < arrayToBeSearched[0].length; column++) {
               if (arrayToBeSearched[row][column] == searchForNum) {
                  rowSpotted[count] = row;  //if the number is found put the row number into the row
                  count++;
               }
          }
      }
      return count; 
  }

 public void printRowSpotted() {
     for(int num : rowSpotted ) {

        System.out.print(num + ',');
     }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    //scanner stuff......
    Journal5b jb = new Journal5b(10,10);
    //get number to be searched for....
   System.out.print("Your number popped up " + jb.countInstance() + ", on rows " + jb.printRowSpotted());

}
```

Comment: It's cool... I'm the one that's suppose to be sorry...I explained it wrong. That and thank you this answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ArrayList` to return the value from `countInstance` instead of using global variables.

```
public ArrayList<Integer> countInstance(int[][] array, int searchForNum) {
    //int count = 0;
    //Use an ArrayList to get the row index
    ArrayList<Integer> countList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < array[0].length; column++) {
            if (array[row][column] == searchForNum) {

                //count++;
                //add row index to the ArrayList count
                countList.add(row);
            }
        }
    }
    return countList;
}
```

and modifying your `main()` method a little bit to print the desired result

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[][] myArray;
    Journal5b j5b = new Journal5b();
    myArray = j5b.createArray(10, 10);
    j5b.print2DArray(myArray);

    int val;
    System.out.println("Enter the number to search for ");
    val = in.nextInt();

    //get the ArrayList from countInstance
    ArrayList<Integer> countList = j5b.countInstance(myArray, val);
    //you can get the number of countInstances by getting the size of the ArrayList
    System.out.print("Your Number popped up " + countList.size() + " times");
    System.out.print(" and is located on row ");

    //Print the values returned by countInstance as desired
    for (int i = 0; i < countList.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print("" + countList.get(i));
        if (i < (countList.size() - 1)) System.out.print(",");
    }
}
```